# Error: Function 'GET_POS' not declared in this scope (opencl)

Tags: c++, opencl

I have a macro at the top of my cl file, `GET_POS`, but I keep getting the title error.

Here's my code:

```
#define GETPOS(r, c, ROWS, COLS) (r*COLS+c)
// more definitions here...

#ifndef blah
#define blah unsigned char
#endif

#ifndef blah
#define blah 1
#endif

#ifndef blah
#define blah 0
#endif


void ec(cell_type* inboard, cell_type* outboard, int position, int rows, int cols) {
    // do stuff

}

void init_g(cell_type* board, int rows, int cols) {
    // do stuff...
}

__kernel void cw(__global cell_type *input, __global cell_type *output, 
int rows, int cols) 
{

int gid1  = get_global_id(0);
int gid2  = get_global_id(1);

init_g(input[0], rows, cols);

ec(input[gid1], output[gid2], GET_POS(gid1,gid2,rows,cols), rows, cols);
}
```

Anybody know why?

Comment: Can you post the full source code?

Comment: Uhh, you `#define GETPOS()` and then try to use `GET_POS()`.

Comment: @kylelutz I'm sorry, this stuff is new to me. Can you explain what that means?

Comment: `GETPOS` is defined at the top of your file but you try to use another macro/function named `GET_POS` which doesn't exist (note the *_*). Change the line in your code to do `GETPOS(gid1,gid2,rows,cols)`.